# Splitting strings with multiple lines in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following string:

"ISL-1027

20:13:02:22:00:76"

i.e. bluetooth name and MAC address

I need MAC address on a separate string. 
What is the best way to use split() in this case?

Thanks

Comment: is there a space between ISL-1027 and 20:13:02:00:76?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split("\n")` you can use this.`"\n"` will be the separator here.

```
   String str = "ISL-1027" +
            "\n" +
            "20:13:02:22:00:76";
    String[] arr= str.split("\n");
    System.out.println("Bluetooth  Name: "+arr[0]);
    System.out.println("MAC address: "+arr[1]);
```

Out put:

```
Bluetooth  Name: ISL-1027
MAC address: 20:13:02:22:00:76
```

If your input String like this `ISL-1027 20:13:02:22:00:76`(separate by a space) use follows

```
    String str = "ISL-1027 20:13:02:22:00:76";      

    String[] arr= str.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Bluetooth  Name: "+arr[0]);
    System.out.println("MAC address: "+arr[1]);
```

Comment: and it will output two seperate strings? Or just the second?

Answer (score 0):

Split matching on any white space and include the [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode switch:

`split("(?s)\\s+");`

The DOTALL will make the regex work despite the presence of newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on that how your string is formated is not sure, but the format of a mac-address is defined. I would not try to split the string and hope that index n is the correct value.
Instead I would use regulare expression to find the correct position of a string that matches the mac-address format.

Here is a litle example (not tested):

```
String input = "ISL-1027

20:13:02:22:00:76"

Pattern macAddrPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\");

String macAdr = parseMacAddr(input);

public String parseMacAddr(String value) {
  Matcher m = macAddrPattern.matcher(value);

  if (m.matches()) {
    return value.substring(m.start(),m.end());
  }

  return null;
}
```

This should always work.